# Wrong value for 'og:type' in facebook debugger

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

On a site I'm developing, I've set the `og:type` as "non_profit" as per Facebook's docs.

When I examine the page with the Facebook debugger / linter, the type is picked up as "profile". I can't seem to find anything wrong with my implementation: it all seems to obey [FB's docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/#types).

Anyone out there got an idea what I'm doing wrong?

---

Update: Here is a link to the site: http://www.hncc.co.uk/

And the code looks like this:

```
<html xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#">
<head>
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Highgate Newtown Community Centre" />
    <meta property="og:title"     content="Highgate Newtown Community Centre" />
    <meta property="og:type"      content="non_profit" />
    <meta property="og:url"       content="http://www.hncc.co.uk" />
    <meta property="og:image"     content="http://www.hncc.co.uk/...link-to-image.png" />
...
```

Comment: OK, updated that. I omitted it at first because I didn't want to spam.

Comment: have you tried setting og:type => website or adding the required fb:app_id parameter?

Comment: @balint I think the 'non_profit' type is better suited than 'website', though.

Answer (score 1):

"profile" is the default object type that Facebook reports for OG objects that report an invalid type. In your case, "non_profit" isn't a built-in type

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/built-in-objects/#external_profile

You either need to use one of the built-in types or create a custom type. More info on that here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/defining-an-object/

Comment: ['non_profit' is listed](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/) on Facebook's docs (under 'object types') - I think that's the page I got it from, but it's a long time ago.

Comment: Interesting. As it's not working, this may be a documentation bug. I'll submit it.

Comment: I work at Facebook.  That's not a type we support.  You should probably be using 'website': https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/object-type